# Swift: Changing the hight of subview programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5, xcode12

I'm implementing a subview but I need to change the subview high programmatically but. This is how I'm changing the high:

```
    func changeHigh() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height - 50)
            
            self.buttonConstraint.constant = 10
        })
    }
```

But the problem with this implementation is animating also the position of the view. All I want is to change the high with out changing the position.

Any of you knows why is changing the position of the subview?

I'll really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to change the height, you can just modify the `size.height` property of the frame.

```
self.frame.size.height -= 50 /// this will make it 50 pts less
```

Also, you should change constraints *outside* the animation block, not inside. Then, call `layoutIfNeeded()` to animate it.

Here's how your code should look:

```
func changeHigh() {
    self.buttonConstraint.constant = 10
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.frame.size.height -= 50
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: ,that works but the container view in the main storyboard is not resizing. Do you know why or resize the container view when I resize the subview?

Comment: Are you using constraints in the storyboard? I will need to see your layout if so

Comment: The high priority has a value of 250. This should resize with the subview. Correct?

Comment: Usually you don't want to mix constraints with frames, so instead of `self.frame.size.height -= 50`, try changing the height constraint from the superview (the container view). So inside the container view's view controller, do something like `self.subViewHeightConstraint.constant -= 50`.